# Прошу помочь в отладке программы

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, заранее извиняюсь за различные ошибки в коде, это первый опыт написания си++ программы.

После компилирования пишет ошибку: Declaration terminated incorrectly

Задание: Дана матрица A=(aij)mxn. Найти минимальные элементы среди отрицательных элементов строк с четными номерами матрицы A. Из них сформировать одномерный массив R=(r1, r2 ,…, rn)/

Вот собственно код:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int m,n, mini;
float **matrix, *R, *min;
void vvod(void)
{
for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
  cout<<"-Intput A["<<j<<"]["<<i<<"]:";
  cin>>*(*(matrix+j)+i);
  }
}
void main(void)
{
  void raschet(void);
  clrscr();
  matrix = new float*[n];
  for (int j=0;j<m;j++)
  matrix[j] = new float[n];
  cout<<"Input size array A:"<<endl;
  cout<<"-Count row M:";
  cin>>m;
  cout<<"-Count colomn N:";
  cin>>n;
  cout<<endl;
  vvod();
  raschet();
  cprintf("\n\n Press any key.");
  getch();
  cout<<*R;
  return;
}
void raschet(void);
 int id=0;
 for (int j=o; j<n-1; j++)
{
   if (j%2!=0)
  {
  for (int i=0; i<m-1; i++)
     {
     min=0;
     if ((*(*matrix+j)+i)=<min) and (*(*(matrix+j)+i)!=0)
        {
        min=*(*(matrix+j)+i);
        *(R+id)=min;
        id++;
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: отредактируй свой пост, выдели весь код и нажми {}

код читать нереально

Comment: спасибо, отредактировал

Comment: Вот тут фигня набита

    void raschet(void);
      int id=0;

Наверное Вы хотели

    void raschet(void) {
      int id=0;

но все скобочки мне считать лень...

Comment: Транслятор возьмите поновее. Современные Ваш код не жруть.

А так: точка с запятой после `void raschet(void);`, неудачное имя переменной `min`, `void main` и т.д.

Comment: @alexlz, да уж... Наверное для качественного обучения и ось сразу надо поменять.

Я бы сразу предложил Linux, emacs, gcc/g++ и make.

Comment: проблема в том что препод в универе просит эту работу исключительно в турбо среде, а все последующие в Borland-овской среде, запрещая использовать что то другое(например визуал студио)

Comment: Да тут в любом случае (независимо от компилятора) куча ошибок.

Память под `R` не выделяется, `min` почему-то указатель, а если посмотреть на

        min=*(*(matrix+j)+i);
        *(R+id)=min;

то должен быть просто переменной,

какой-то `and` вместо `&&` в 

    ((*(*matrix+j)+i)=<min) and (*(*(matrix+j)+i)!=0)

и т.д.


Вообще, программа не решает задачу

    Найти минимальные элементы среди отрицательных элементов строк с четными номерами матрицы A

она ничего специфического не делает если все элементы неотрицательные.